# Not able to run mjpg_streamer from a shell script run by a Java process

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm new to Linux. My shell script is streamscript.sh

Contents are:

```
/usr/local/bin/mjpg_streamer -i "input_uvc.so -y -f 100 -r 640*480" -o "output_http.so -w /usr/local/www"
```

Java Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
       String target = "/home/pi/java_project_gf/streamscript.sh";
       ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(target);
       pb.start();
} catch(Exception ex){
       System.out.println("Exception thrown" + ex.getMessage());
}

}
```

If I write `mkdir dummyDir` in the shell script, it is creating the directory. But mjpg_streamer is NOT running.

Comment: What exactly is happening when you run your Java code? Is there any output?

Comment: No Nothing , It will be blank.

Comment: Try adding `echo "test"` to your script, or perhaps `echo "test" 1>&2` (after investigating what these commands do. Also, can you run the same script manually?

Comment: By default, `ProcessBuilder` directs stdout/err to pipes. You can change that by calling `inheritIO()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225663/problem-processbuilder-running-script-sh

Comment: @Arkadiy I can run the same script manually from terminal it works fine. As a test I have added "mkdir" command in the script and it created the dir as well when I run from java code . FYI, mjpg_streamer is a server which access the webcam connected to Pi through localhost.

Comment: Another possibility is that the server starts, then java process exist and the server is killed.